# Clickhouse cluster setup with zookpeer in Docker in Windows Machine

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

I created three zookeeper nodes in docker with the following commands.

```sh
docker run -d -p 2181:2181 --name zookeeper_node1 --privileged --restart always --network zoonet --ip 172.18.0.2 -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node1/volumes/data:/data -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node1/volumes/datalog:/datalog -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node1/volumes/logs:/logs -e ZOO_MY_ID=1 -e "ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=172.18.0.2:2888:3888;2181 server.2=172.18.0.3:2888:3888;2181 server.3=172.18.0.4:2888:3888;2181" 36c607e7b14d


docker run -d -p 2182:2181 --name zookeeper_node2 --privileged --restart always --network zoonet --ip 172.18.0.3 -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node2/volumes/data:/data -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node2/volumes/datalog:/datalog -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node2/volumes/logs:/logs -e ZOO_MY_ID=2 -e "ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=172.18.0.2:2888:3888;2181 server.2=172.18.0.3:2888:3888;2181 server.3=172.18.0.4:2888:3888;2181" 36c607e7b14d


docker run -d -p 2183:2181 --name zookeeper_node3 --privileged --restart always --network zoonet --ip 172.18.0.4 -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node3/volumes/data:/data -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node3/volumes/datalog:/datalog -v C:/zookeeper/zk_node3/volumes/logs:/logs -e ZOO_MY_ID=3 -e "ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=172.18.0.2:2888:3888;2181 server.2=172.18.0.3:2888:3888;2181 server.3=172.18.0.4:2888:3888;2181" 36c607e7b14d
```

The above three zookeeper nodes are in a network called zoonet.

I have changed the config files and started a clickhouse node in zoonet(existing in docker). I used the below command to start the clickhouse node.

```sh
docker run -d -p 8125:8123 -p 9001:9000 -p 9019:9009  --name=ck_node-1 --privileged --network zoonet --ip 172.18.0.5  --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 -v C:/some-clickhouse-server/ck-node-1/data:/var/lib/clickhouse:rw -v C:/some-clickhouse-server/ck-node-1/conf:/etc/clickhouse-server:rw -v C:/some-clickhouse-server/ck-node-1/log:/var/log/clickhouse-server:rw  d846490c0466
```

It started the node and exited.

Can someone please help me how bring click house node into zoonet.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to volume clickhouse data folder `-v C:/some-clickhouse-server/ck-node-1/data:/var/lib/clickhouse:rw`

only logs
`-v C:/some-clickhouse-server/ck-node-1/logs:/var/log/clickhouse-server/:rw`

cause Windows 10 + WSL2 (I hope you use latest Docker Desktop) will mount this with 0777 rights and wrong file and folder owner, clickhouse-server will check it and fail during restart